# What does it mean: You can't use `\hrule' here except with leaders

Tags: plain-tex

I have the following example, which draws a vertical line at the top of the paper:

```
\def\makeheadline{
  \setbox0=\hbox to 0pt{\hskip-1in\hskip15cm \vrule depth 3cm \hss}
  \ht0=0pt \dp0=0pt
  \vbox to 0pt{\vskip-1in \box0 \vss}
  % orignal \makeheadline follows
  \vbox to 0pt{\vskip-22.5pt
    \line{\vbox to 8.5pt{}\the\headline}\vss}\nointerlineskip}
Hello World!
\bye
```

Now I want to add an additional horizontal line. I tried it this way:

```
\def\makeheadline{
  \setbox0=\hbox to 0pt{\hskip-1in\hskip15cm \vrule depth 3cm \hss}
  \ht0=0pt \dp0=0pt
  \setbox0=\hbox to 0pt{\hskip-1in \hrule width 15cm \hss}
  \ht0=0pt \dp0=0pt
  \vbox to 0pt{\vskip-1in \box0 \vss}
  % orignal \makeheadline follows
  \vbox to 0pt{\vskip-22.5pt
    \line{\vbox to 8.5pt{}\the\headline}\vss}\nointerlineskip}
Hello World!
\bye
```

But this throws the error:

> ```
> ! You can't use `\hrule' here except with leaders.
> ```

Can anybody explain what is wrong with the hrule?

Comment: `\vrule height 0.4pt width 15cm`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The primitive `\hrule` is a *vertical command*; when TeX encounters it, it switches to vertical mode, emitting `\par` if it is in (unrestricted) horizontal mode.

Because of this, it cannot appear inside `\hbox`.

To the contrary, `\vrule` is a *horizontal command*, so it triggers starting a paragraph if found in vertical mode.

In your case `\vrule height 0.4pt width 15cm` will do.

Comment: Why is it "except with leaders"?

Comment: @errekak If you want to realize a horizontal rule with leaders, you need `\leaders\hrule\hskip<skip>`.